# Is Probability just Math?

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, philosophical

Is Probability just a *"branch of mathematics"* as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) suggests or is it something larger than that?
More like we use math for real world problems like engineering, medicine, meteorology or astrophysics, that go beyond math; I think of probability and statistics as an area of knowledge that we try to understand using math, but goes it beyond that.

And this is maybe the reason, it is often hard and counter-intuitive, to translate mathematics into real world answers.

> A mathematician can tell you that getting 100 heads in a row is no less likely than any other outcome when tossing a fair coin 100 times. A statistician will suspect the coin is biased.

Comment: "Probability *and* statistics", or probability? How do you define "larger than mathematics"? The mathematician in the quote used probability theory to make the claim, so you seem to be answering yourself, aren't you?

Comment: Note that 100 heads in a row is no less likely than any other *specific sequence of heads and tails*. It is of course vastly less probabey than an outcome of 51 heads and 49 tails *in any order*. Which any mathematician will understand.